# What modal's style not working in bootstrap v 3.1.0

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my modal:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
              <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal Heading</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <h4>Text in ao78o78o978o modal</h4>
              <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem.</p>

              <h4>Popover in a modal</h4>
              <p>This <a href="#" role="button" class="btn popover-test" title="" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?" data-original-title="A Title">button</a> should trigger a popover on click.</p>

              <h4>Tooltips in a modal</h4>
              <p><a href="#" class="tooltip-test" title="" data-original-title="Tooltip">This link</a> and <a href="#" class="tooltip-test" title="" data-original-title="Tooltip">that link</a> should have tooltips on hover.</p>

              <hr>

              <h4>Overflowing text to show optional scrollbar</h4>
              <p>We set a fixed <code>max-height</code> on the <code>.modal-body</code>. Watch it overflow with all this extra lorem ipsum text we've included.</p>
              <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
              <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
              <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
              <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
              <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
              <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
<div class="bs-docs-example" style="padding-bottom: 24px;">
    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Launch demo modal</a>
</div>
```

when I downgrade bootstrap.css from 3.1.0 to 2.32 modal style is very good and fix.And other styles notworking...
what V3.1 not support modals??

Comment: this is my problem :((

Comment: Bootstrap 3 requires different markup for modals, see the docs: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docs of modals :
[Modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

its a sample:

```
<div id="C_US" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                </div>
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the `<div class="modal-dialog">` and `<div class="modal-content">` elements as described in the Bootstrap [docs for modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

JSBin [here](http://jsbin.com/eRASAveX/1/edit?html,output).

Comment: Oh Yes!.I'm sorry for this question...  Now I hand fix and edit modal styles in bootstrap.css and fix it!!! but your vay is standard